# PLSQL developer process killed - runs plqsl block on DB server?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I could not wait for finishing of running long long term plsql block and had to turn off PC. PLSQL developer process was killed. My question is how to determine if the block is still running on server (or was stopped with plsql dev. process kill) without waiting for couple of hours?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open another PLSQL Developer instance, spawn the "Sessions" window and browse the sessions if you see your previous session as `ACTIVE`.

... or ...

Open another PLSQL Developer instance, spawn the "SQL" window and browse the sessions with SQL (which is, essentially, the same as above) ...

```
select S.sid, S.serial#, S.status, S.osuser, Q.sql_fulltext
from v$session S
    left join v$sql Q
        on Q.sql_id = S.sql_id
where schemaname = '&yourBlocksSchemaName'
    and S.sid != userenv('sid')
;
```

Comment: Session was inactive, forgot to mention this. But I didn't know it this means that the process which was started on this session is no more running on server. Thanks

Comment: @morganzd, I hate to nitpick, but if my answer helped you, you should accept it and/or upvote it. That's how it goes here, on stackoverflow.com.